# Resolving tokens in Beanshell

Tags: java, beanshell

I want to use beanshell (bsh) to evaluate user defined expressions. I want to allow those expressions to have a kind of macro substitution for example:

`boolean isTrue = i.eval("@something == 5");`

Is there a way to have bsh call back to my java for substitution of variables when it parses the above example before evaluation?

**EDIT**
My intent is to allow a user to specify the expression (e.g. `@something == 5`) where `@something` is a key and requires a substitution to the actual value. I want to be able to pass in the whole evaluation string as stated by the user and would like beanshell to call back to a 'resolver' type handler during the parse.

Thanks in advance
-- Frank

Comment: Or anything (Rhino, etc.) that would support this

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to achive this in beanshell.
You could post a feature request for this at http://code.google.com/p/beanshell2

But perhaps you give some more insights in what you try to achive..?

Comment: Not really. Why don't you the existing possibilities? I.e. 'Interpreter i = new Interpreter(); i.set(something, 5); i.eval("something == 5");'

Answer (score 0):

A really old question, but here's my answer:

1. Set your resolver as a varible on the Interpreter

`Interpreter i = new Interpreter();
 i.set("resolver", myResolver);`

2. Process tokens

Pre-process user input for the pattern `@something` into a regex, or whatever, in order to render your script token as:

```
resolver.resolve("@something") == 5
```

3. Execute script (I left out \" for clarity since this will be a variable)

`i.eval("resolver.resolve("@something") == 5")`

The resolve method can return an object; Beanshell loose-typing and auto-boxing should take care of stuff. The issue I see is things like String.equals(), for example, since that requires more than just token subsitution.